# Comparison of numeric vector column with numeric column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate the occurrence of y in the vector x in the same row.
However, I can only manage to do the calculation with a fixed y (2 in my example).

```
dt <- data.table(x = list(c(1,1,1,1,1),
                          c(2,2,2),
                          c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                          c(2, 2, 3, 3)),
                 y = c(2, 2, 3, 3))

dt[, occurrence := sapply(sapply(x, function(z) {z == 2}), mean)]

> dt
           x y occurrence
1: 1,1,1,1,1 2       0.00
2:     2,2,2 2       1.00
3:   1,2,3,4 3       0.25
4:   2,2,3,3 3       0.50
```

How can I make this line work?

```
dt[, occurrence := sapply(sapply(x, function(z) {z == y}), mean)]
```

Comment: Try this `dt[, occurrence := mean(unlist(x)==y), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]`

Comment: Thanks, that works